# how to get C# code to read XML file in a basic game

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating a basic text based rpg and am trying to use xml to save games. This is the code that calls the players data from an xml:

```
public class SuperAdventure() {
    private Player _player;

    private Monster _currentMonster;

    private const string PLAYER_DATA_FILE_NAME = "PlayerData.xml";

    public SuperAdventure()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (File.Exists(PLAYER_DATA_FILE_NAME))
        {
            _player = Player.CreatePlayerFromXmlString(File.ReadAllText(PLAYER_DATA_FILE_NAME));
        }
        else
        {
            _player = Player.CreateDefaultPlayer();
        }

        MoveTo(_player.CurrentLocation);
        UpdatePlayerStats();
    }
}
```

I also know for sure that the xml is being created correctly. When I close the game, I can manually find the xml. All the stats are saved but when the game is reopened the player is reset to the default stats and items. I'm not sure if the order of the function calling would matter or if the creation of the xml would affect the games use of the xml.

Here's the CreatePlayerFromXmlString() function:

```
        public static Player CreatePlayerFromXmlString(string xmlPlayerData)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument playerData = new XmlDocument();

            playerData.LoadXml(xmlPlayerData);

            int currentHitPoints = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/CurrentHItPoints").InnerText);
            int maximumHitPoints = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/MaximumHitPoints").InnerText);
            int gold = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/Gold").InnerText);
            int experiencePoints = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/ExperiencePoints").InnerText);

            Player player = new Player(currentHitPoints, maximumHitPoints, gold, experiencePoints);

            int currentLocationID = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/CurrentLocation").InnerText);
            player.CurrentLocation = World.LocationByID(currentLocationID);

            foreach (XmlNode node in playerData.SelectNodes("/Player/InventoryItems/InventoryItem"))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["ID"].Value);
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["Quantity"].Value);

                for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
                {
                    player.AddItemToInventory(World.ItemByID(id));
                }
            }

            foreach (XmlNode node in playerData.SelectNodes("/Player/PlayerQuests/PlayerQuest"))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["ID"].Value);
                bool isCompleted = Convert.ToBoolean(node.Attributes["IsCompleted"].Value);

                PlayerQuest playerQuest = new PlayerQuest(World.QuestByID(id));
                playerQuest.IsCompleted = isCompleted;

                player.Quests.Add(playerQuest);
            }

            return player;
        }
        catch
        {
            //If there was an error with the XML data, return a default player object
            return Player.CreateDefaultPlayer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused, the title of your question makes it sounds like you don't have a working XML solution for your game's needs, but your code seems to suggest otherwise.  How are you creating/interacting with your XML file?

Comment: The xml file save to a folder in visual studio with the solution. When the game runs it should go and check for an xml file to create an existing player unless there is no xml file. In that case it make a new default player.

Comment: Where is this directory in relation to the root folder of your project? The root folder will be the one that contains the .sln file.

Comment: Depending on this, you may be either blowing away your files or not even referencing them at all.  I expect that the latter is the case.

Comment: So you think I'm calling the wrong file?

Comment: I'm not sure, it is possible, but I need more information so I can help ya. Please tell me the path where the directory that houses the file is at.  is it `bin\debug`?  if so, are you performing Rebuild every time you press start?

Comment: bin\release; I have rebuilt it using visual studio and started the app with the executable.

Comment: So if you debug the constructor, which line executes unexpectedly? Let me know if you need help with that, too. Can walk you through it.

Comment: I'll need help debugging, I haven't gotten into that much yet

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: Go ahead and set a breakpoint on `if (File.Exists(PLAYER_DATA_FILE_NAME))`.  If we skip to the else statement, we'll know that it is not finding your file.  If we manage to make it to the `_player = Player.CreatePlayerFromXmlString(File.ReadAllText(PLAYER_DATA_FILE_NAME));` then you'll need to share the code for `Player.CreatePlayerFromXmlString(...)` to see whats going wrong.  Also, if you look up at the top of visual studio, are you in Debug mode or Release mode?

Comment: I'm in debug mode,

Comment: Do you not have that PlayerData.xml in bin\debug as well?

Comment: I do now, I had been using release

Comment: If your program is reaching the line `_player= Player.CreatePlayerFromXMLString`, please add that code to your problem description.

Comment: It's reaching the line and I added the code, I apologize for confusing you and being a little difficult, this post is my first question so I'm not really sure how to do this yet

Comment: No worries man, everybody has to start somewhere.  So first thing I see is that you've got a big try/catch block.  Catch means you're going to write the default.  So, my bet is that you're throwing an Exception somewhere in the try block, its getting caught by the catch block, and then you just use the CreateDefault function.  Don't know if you know what any of that is, bounce it back at me.

Comment: The program is definitely getting into the try block.

Comment: The problem is somewhere between int currentHitPoints and int maximumHitPoints lines

Comment: So try to debug for a little bit.  Keep pressing the Step Over button (aka run next line)  Let me know which line is the last line to be run before you jump to the catch block and execute CreateDefaultPlayer.

Comment: change your catch-block to be `catch(Exception e) { ...` and when you get to the catch block, hover your mouse over e and let me know what the exception message is.

Comment: The problem was I had missed spelled currentHitPoints, currentHItPoints, which didn't exists in the XML

Comment: Problem solved. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when the game went through the try block of code there was an error. This caused it to move to the catch block and create a default player instead. The string in the line of code searching for the currentHitPoints is misspelled-visual studio didn't see it as an error because it was a string passed into an XML function.

```
int currentHitPoints = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/CurrentHItPoints").InnerText);
```

The `"/Player/Stats/CurrentHItPoints"` should be `"/Player/Stats/CurrentHitPoints"`

Comment: Spelling is very important when typing a string, especially if you have a spell check in your program editor.